# USB camera not detected

Tags: drivers, usb, webcam, logitech

I picked up a Logitech c920 USB camera, which is apparently meant to be plug and play on Ubuntu. It's registering on my USB devices when I run `$ lsusb`, but doesn't show up on Cheese or any other application. Oddly though, the microphone on the camera is picked up (for instance on google meetings, firefox displays it as an option for microphone).

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.4.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04f2:b5c0 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 027: ID 046d:082d Logitech, Inc. HD Pro Webcam C920
```

...

```
$ lsusb -v
Bus 001 Device 026: ID 046d:082d Logitech, Inc. HD Pro Webcam C920
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
```

and then follows tons of lines of details

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a machine that supports USB 3.0

If you are using VMWare or Virtual box to use Ubuntu as guest, check if you have enabled USB 3.0 in settings.
For Virtual Box -> Settings -> USB -> USB 3.0 (xHCI) Controller.

If you are using Ubuntu as host, maybe check if USB 3.0 drivers are working

[How do I get usb 3.0 driver working or check that it is already working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/729558/how-do-i-get-usb-3-0-driver-working-or-check-that-it-is-already-working)